# How to make y axis labels horizontal but keep y-axis title parallel?

Tags: r, plotrix

I would like to make my y axis labels horizontal, while keeping my y axis titles as parallel.
When I try inputting las=1 into the twoor.plot()argument, nothing happens. I have also tried ylas=1, y_las=1, lylas=1, rylas=1, and nothing happens. The only way I've been able to make my yaxis labels horizontal, is by using par(las=1), but then this makes my y-axis titles horizontal too, which I don't want...

This is my code so far:

```
  par(las=1)
    yFrequency <- c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160)
    GS_class_labels <- c("<2", "2-4", "4-8", "8-16", "16-32", "32-64", "64-128", "128<")
    twoord.plot(data=distribution,lx="Var1",ly="Freq", ry="cum_percentile",
                main="B1 Surface Grain Size Distribution",
                xlim=NULL,lylim=c(0,160),rylim=NULL,lwd=1.5,
                lcol=1,rcol=2,xlab="Grain Size (mm)",lytickpos=yFrequency, 
                ylab="Frequency",ylab.at=NA,
                rytickpos=NA,rylab="Percent Finer Than (%)",rylab.at=NA,
                lpch=1,rpch=2,
                type="b",xtickpos=NULL,xticklab=GS_class_labels,
                halfwidth=0.4,axislab.cex=1.1,
                do.first=NULL,xaxt="s", yticklab=yFrequency, cex.lab=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative way to set the y axis labels parallel is as follows.
(1) Set both of the `ylab` and `rylab` from `twoord.plot` to empty.
(2) Use `mtext` and set the parameters accordingly.

Here is the code to do that. Because you don't provide the `distribution` data, I use `iris` data just to make it possible to generate the plot.

```
# Emptying both of ylab and rylab

twoord.plot(data = iris,lx="Sepal.Length",ly="Petal.Width", ry="Sepal.Width",
            main="B1 Surface Grain Size Distribution",
            xlim=NULL,lylim=c(0,160),rylim=NULL,lwd=1.5,
            lcol=1,rcol=2,xlab="Grain Size (mm)",lytickpos=yFrequency, 
            ylab="",ylab.at=NA,
            rytickpos=NA,rylab="",rylab.at=NA,
            lpch=1,rpch=2,
            type="b",xtickpos=NULL,xticklab=GS_class_labels,
            halfwidth=0.4,axislab.cex=1.1,
            do.first=NULL,xaxt="n",yaxt="n", #yticklab=yFrequency, 
            cex.lab=1)

# Assign the previous labels of ylab and rylab to the *text* parameter of *mtext*. 
# side = 2 means the left side. side = 4 means the right side.
# las = 0 is the parallel style of the text. 
# line shows the distance of the text from the y axis. 

mtext(text = "Frequency", side = 2, las = 0, line = 2.5)
mtext(text = "Percent Finer Than (%)", side = 4, las = 0, line = 0.5)
```

The resulted plot:

[image]

Comment: Glad it helps. Please kindly accept my answer.